# How to use findAll in Grails with "if" statement to verify if the field is null before searching

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I need to create a `findAll` criteria in Grails, but I have 4 fields to search. I just need to search by those fields if a specific variable is not null.

For example, if all variables are not null, I'll search by all the fields like the following:

```
list = MyObject.findAll {
    'in'("job", jobList)
    'in'("businessUnit", businessUnitList)
    'in'("company", companyList)
    eq("regularTime", params.regularTime)
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
regularTimeList = RegularTime.findAll {
    if(params.job != null)  'in'("job", jobList)
    if(params.businessUnit != null)  'in'("businessUnit", businessUnitList)
    if(params.company != null)  'in'("company", companyList)
    if(params.regularTime != null)  eq("regularTime", params.domainClassSearchFilters.regularTime)
 }
```

It's not working so I'd like to know if there is a way to do that because right now I had to create a lot of ifs to verify them... I need one if to each scenario... Like:

If `job` is not null and `company` is not null, one findAll. If `company` is not null and regularTime is not null, another `findAll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened, but the way Above didn't work for me...
I solved it using criteria.

```
list= MyObject.createCriteria().list {
                if(params.job != null && "" != params.domainClassSearchFilters.job )
                    'in'("job", jobList)
                if(params.businessUnit != null && "" != params.businessUnit)
                    'in'("businessUnit", businessUnitList)
                if(params.company != null && "" != params.company)
                    'in'("company", companyList)
                if(params.regularTime != null && "" != params.regularTime && params.regularTime.isDouble())
                    eq("regularTime", Double.parseDouble(params.regularTime))
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
regularTimeList = RegularTime.findAll {  
    if (params.job != null) params.job in jobList  
    if (params.businessUnit != null) params.businessUnit in businessUnitList  
    if (params.company != null) params.company in companyList  
    if (params.regularTime != null) regularTime == params.domainClass  
}
```